# Installing Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to install Rails 3.1.

It says to use 'gem install rails --pre' in the announcement blog post here:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate

When I try

> $ gem install rails --pre

I get the error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
>   uninitialized constant Syck::Syck

What to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding your specific problem: You may be seeing an error introduced by a faulty build of Rails 3.0.8.rc3 that got pushed as "rails --pre". See this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1412) in the Rails repository.

Instead of

> gem install rails --pre

for the newest version, use

> gem install rails -v ">=3.1.0rc"

or for 3.1.0.rc1 specifically:

> gem install rails --version=3.1.0.rc1

See the guide referenced above for more advice.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me and the link was useful.

Comment: Ooh! An actual explanation of the problem, rather than my parroting the solution. +1 :D

Comment: I didn't know that `--pre` was broken currently. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I googled this error message and found [the following comment on the Riding Rails blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate#comment-28899):

> I’ve met the same
>
> `ERROR: While executing gem …
>   (NameError) uninitialized constant
>   Syck::Syck`
>
> issue with: `gem install rails --pre`
>
> Get around with: `gem install rails -v
>   ”>=3.1.0rc”`

Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: ”>=3.1.0rc” is a good suggestion for future-proofing the answer. I've updated my answer to incorporate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

An awesome guide for installing rails is www.installrails.com - that will probably help fix your problem.